# How can I install the Currency module on shared host?

Tags: 8

I want to install the Currency module on Drupal 8, but it doesn't install.

> Currency requires Composer dependencies. Read the documentation on how to install them.

I am using a shared host, and I can't use Composer. How can I do it?

Comment: Do it locally then copy the files to the shared hosting platform. Bit of a pain but it'll work

Comment: You say that I copy all drupal files or only Currency module files to the shared hosting platform?

Comment: Who can help me ?

Comment: Exactly what Clive said. Use composer locally to get dependencies for your site, upload your new vendor directory to your shared host.